# Primefaces 6.1 png image display with black background

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, background, png, transparent

I'm having difficult to display png image in my PrimeFaces 6.1.

Image was loaded from Database in byte array format. jpg is displaying well but png displayed always with black background.

This is my code Snippet for jsf:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{fileControlBean.image}">
   <f:param name="fileId" value="#{file.fileId}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

and back bean as:

```
public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
    else {
        // So, browser is requesting the image. Return a real StreamedContent with the image bytes.
        String fileId = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("fileId");
        File file = (File) fileBean.getFileCache().get(fileId);
        return new ByteArrayContent(file.getThumbnail(),file.getFileType(),file.getFileName());
    }
}
```

All other jpg display properly, but png image looks transparent was set to 1. My question: How I can set it back to transparent? or it is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, This quest is not properly asked. The black background issue was caused by png self as it comes with transparency issue. I used inkscape regenerate the png again. the black background gone.